# click not triggered at first time for blur event at the time of showing hidden element inside form

Tags: jquery, blur

Well, may be you didn't understand anything by seeing the title (question). To be honest, I can't define the question for the issue. But, I am sure that you'll understand the issue after seeing my example.

There is a hidden div and an `input` inside a `form`. At the time of `focusout` from input, some action will be done. Another set of actions will be done by clicking the `submit` button.

Here is my HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
     $('#name').blur(function() { 
        console.log('blured');
        $('.message').show();
      });
      
      $('body').on('click', '.submitBtn', function () {
        console.log('click on Button');
      });
    })
```

```css
.message {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <div class="message">
    <p>
      Test Message
    </p>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  <button type="submit" class="submitBtn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The issue is: after typing something at the input, if I click on the submit button, click event hasn't been triggered. It's triggering from second click.

[image]

You can see that, message, `click on Button` hasn't been printed on the console. If I click again on the `submit` button, then the message is being printed.

If I disable this code: `//$('.message').show();` then everything work as expected. I don't understand why is the issue happened?

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learner73/96wv5fze/12/)**

Comment: From the looks of your Fiddle, everything technically works fine. However one caveat I've noticed that by `show`ing the message, you move content down, including the button you may be trying to click. So, if you try to click the button while the input has focus, what happens is the `blur` handler is called first, showing the message, and then because the button has moved down you don't actually manage to hit the button by the time you release the mouse button. To test, try moving the message `div` below the input and button and see if things behave more like you're expecting.

Comment: @Deji, you are right! I got the reason now. But, I need the message div above the input box and inside the form. Any solution for that?

Comment: I'd say the simplest solution (arguably better from a design standpoint too) is to reserve the space occupied by the hidden element (effectively use the `visibility` property) even before it's shown. In that way you avoid elements moving around on the page when you do show them, thus providing a better UX: https://jsfiddle.net/sdhtmk90/

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue here is nothing to do with the events themselves not being right but rather the sequence in which they occur not being accounted for.

When you are focused on the input and you click the button, the events are effectively called in the following sequence: `input loses focus / blur`, `document receives "click"`

It's important to note as well that the action of clicking itself apparently doesn't immediately capture information about *what* was clicked on, only *where* the click took place, and in this situation an element with focus lose that focus and call upon any event listeners *before* a new element is identified as the target for the click.

This means that any changes made to the document during the "blur" listeners, for example target element being removed from the document, will happen *before* the target element has its click event listeners called - or even before the browser registers it as the "target" element at all.

In the case of this question, a block of content above the button and hidden with `display:none` is being revealed with `display:block` when the input field loses focus, which moves content including the button down in the page to make room for its appearance, and thus causes the "click" to actually *miss* the button.

The following Fiddle shows a working solution to this problem, using the visibility property rather than `display`, in order to reserve the space taken up by the hidden message rather than causing content to move around once it is revealed, which used correctly is also a better practise in terms of UX:
https://jsfiddle.net/sdhtmk90/

Comment: I've understood that issue here is nothing to do with the events themselves. I am implementing this in a system where error/response message appear from `display: none;` to `display: block;`To keep the consistency in existing UX, I can't apply this visibility solution of CSS. As I understand the reason for the issue now, I am able to solve it another way in my project. There will be more input box after the first input and blur event only work for the first input. So, I will find some UX solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use focus instead of blur

```
$('#name').focus(function() { 
    console.log('blured');
    $('.message').show();
  });
```

Why you schould use that? Becouse The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus.

so 1st click on input = focus

when click anywhere else after clicked on input = blur

If you need action when user leave cursor from input field instead of click outside input field do it like that:

```
$('#name').focus(function() {
  $(this).mouseout(function() {
    console.log('blured');
    $('.message').show();})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `click` event requires `mouseup` to fire immediately after `mousedown`.
But here when yo click `button.submitBtn`, the event sequence becomes `mousedown` `blur` `mouseup`. So the `click` event is never fired for the first time. 
So you can try using `mousedown` instead of `click` and delay the `mousedown` handler by a small period of time.

```
$('body').on('click', '.submitBtn', function () {
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('click on Button');
},100);
});
```

Comment: does `mouseout` work from mobile device? It seems that `mouseout`, `mousedown` don't work properly for `Tab` keyword from keyboard from pc.